# How to apply EventListener to each element of an array?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to apply onclick eventlistener on each of the elements in an array. How can I do that? I tried using querySelectorAll but it doesn't work. You can check the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-ishizaka-4g9uq?file=/src/App.js:93-229. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
let head = document.querySelectorAll("heading");
    for (let i of head)
      i.addEventListener("click", function h() {
        let a = document.getElementById("subheading");
        a.style.display = "none";
      });
```

Comment: Your code is looking for `<heading>...</heading>` elements. [HTML doesn't have a `heading` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#elements-3), is that something custom? Or a class name? Or an ID? Separately: `"Not working" how? What happens? What do you see when you use the debugger?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: (Glances at external site anyway). . If you are using React then use React. Do not use direct DOM manipulation. They do not play nicely together.

Comment: I have 2 arrays. One array has Headings so I gave the id="heading" in html. When I click to the element of Heading array i.e. 1. Heading, it should hide the subheadings underneath it. While using with getElementById, it applies to only first element. But I want to apply to all elements in Heading's array. You may check the code in sandbox. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: `querySelectorAll`, `addEventListener`, `getElementsById` etc. have nothing to do in a React application. That's not how React works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-feather-tx821?file=/src/App.js)

Errors:

1. You can need to give class-names `headings` to elements because HTML document have only one unique id.
2. While looping over element in `useEffect`  you need to find `const a = i.querySelector(".subheading")` like this.

Link to [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-feather-tx821?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const headings = ["1. Heading", "2. Heading", "3. Heading"];
  const subheadings = ["1. Subheading", "2. Subheading", "3. Subheading"];

  useEffect(() => {
    const head = document.querySelectorAll(".heading");

    head.forEach((i) => {
      i.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const a = i.querySelector(".subheading");
        a.style.display = "none";
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {headings.map((val, index) => (
          <li key={index} style={{ listStyle: "none" }} className="heading">
            <a href="#">{val}</a>
            <ul className="subheading">
              {subheadings.map((val, index2) => (
                <li key={index2} style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
                  <a href="#">{val}</a>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Link to [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-feather-tx821?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer because it still uses things that have nothing to do in a React app (querySelectorAll, addEventListener("click") etc). That's not how React works. You don't hide an element in React by selecting it, then setting `style.display = "none"`. You don't bind a click event with `addEventListener("click")`. This is just plain wrong.

Comment: @JeremyThille I agree with your comment. But i just solved the issue in code. I was not talking about react ways of doing things. I was just solving which was not working.

Comment: Thanks Ferin for the help. I tried with everything but the issue was that I was using a = document.querySelector(".subheading") instead of a = i.querySelector(".subheading"). This has solved the issue.

Comment: @xiang `document.querySelectorAll("heading")`  This was also the issue, you are trying to find HTML heading tag here.

Comment: @xiang Really, you should learn how to use React. Either use good old plain Javascript with `querySelectorAll`, `style.display = "none"`, _OR_ use React. Don't mix both together.

Comment: Yes @JeremyThille thanks for your suggestion. Can you recommend any doc of similar way of doing in React?

Comment: Well, any of the million of free tutorials out there, as well as the official documentation, will show you how to attach a click handler. A simple Google search immediately led me to `<button onClick={this.sayHello}>` as well as [How to show or hide elements](https://reactgo.com/react-show-hide-elements/).

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks a lot.